# Problema con https y ajax

Tags: laravel, ajax

Tengo una app en Laravel, en la cual tengo un controlador que calcula los ingresos y gastos de los usuarios, luego son retornados y capturados usando ajax para poder mostrar los datos en forma de gráfica.

Pero esto me genera un conflicto debido a que estoy utilizando HTTPS en mi app. He intentado poner la etiqueta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

Esto funciona, pero no creo que sea la solucion mas adecuada ademas de que al entrar a la app por primera vez me da error y no se ven los iconos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si entro a otra parte de la app y vuelvo al home entonces si funciona.

Este es mi codigo ajax:

```
ajaxGetPostMonthlyData: function () {
        var urlPath =  'https://' + window.location.hostname + '/get-post-chart-data';
        var request = $.ajax( {
            method: 'GET',
            url: urlPath
    } );
```

Comment: Por lo que veo no estas en el localhost, si tu dominio no tienen un certificado ssl no podrás tener el https y se quedara como no seguro

Comment: @christian ya tengo el certificado ssl, el problema es que los datos los estoy pasando por http.

Comment: Has intentado con omitir el ```https``` de tu petición

Comment: @christian, si. He probado de las dos maneras.